# array from an array of arrays - Swift iOS

Tags: arrays, swift

I have my current array like this...

```
[
  ["Ahmedabad"],
  ["Surat"],
  ["Rajkot"],
  ["Junagadh"],
  ["Jamnagar"],
  ["Bhavnagar"],
  ["Amreli"]
]
```

And I want output in single String array **[String]** like..

```
["Ahmedabad", "Surat", "Rajkot", "Junagadh", "Jamnagar", "Bhavnagar", "Amreli"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution you can apply:

```
let cityListarrays = [
  ["Ahmedabad"],
  ["Surat"],
  ["Rajkot"],
  ["Junagadh"],
  ["Jamnagar"],
  ["Bhavnagar"],
  ["Amreli"]
]

let newListArray = cityListarrays.flatMap { object in
    object
}

print(newListArray)
```

**Output**:

```
["Ahmedabad", "Surat", "Rajkot", "Junagadh", "Jamnagar", "Bhavnagar", "Amreli"]
```

Comment: Why not simply `cityListarrays.joined()`?

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried but it gives..

FlattenSequence<Array<Array<String>>>(_base: [["Ahmedabad"], ["Surat"], ["Rajkot"], ["Junagadh"], ["Jamnagar"], ["Bhavnagar"], ["Amreli"]])

Comment: That's correct. If you need an array you have to initialize it `Array(cityListarrays.joined())` but this will duplicate the memory usage.